# IOS/IPHONE Safari or Chrome viewing local files

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome, safari

I have created a stand-alone HTML, CSS, JavaScript offline map view using Leaflet (see leafletjs.com). I can use FileApp/DiskAid to download the application to the iphone. I can tap on the HTML file and view the app, but as you can see from the attached screen shot, the layers and zoom controls are at the top of the screen. If I try and press them then your HTML viewer with block the press and slide down a banner (BACK, ACTIONS, etc) (the black top banner that your viewer shows).

1. Better yet, I would like to open it with SAFARI since it has the NITRO JS engine, but the only OPEN IN options I get are Evernote, RiddleDocs, Mover, and DropBox.
2. Is there way to tell safari or chrome for IOS to open up a local file system where the html is: http:// 127.0.0.1/fileApp/Toby.html for example where Toby is my HTML file? I realize is somewhere it the data for t

[image: Screenshot of Leaflet app running on iPhone]

[image: Hidden by bar]

Answer (score 0):

First Step :-

These options are configured using keys in your **Info.plist** file. The first key is **UIFileSharingEnabled**, which enables iTunes sharing of files in your Documents folder. The second key is **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace**, which grants the local file provider access to files in your Documents folder. Add these keys to your **Info.plist** and set their values to **YES**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhaaL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZRJ.png)

let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)

```
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can use option either to import or export files from app. Also you can define the type of files you want to export or import...